# top level function vs Any. in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Which of the Top Level Function and extension Any better to have a function everywhere in the project?

**Top level functio**n

```
package com.test

fun A(){

}
```

**Extension Any**

```
package com.test

fun Any.A(){

}
```

Comment: they do not serve the same purpose. You cannot say one or the other is better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Any.A()` extension function would be available on all object instance, while the `A()` function is available "statically". So if you don't need to use `this` within `A()`, you should not put it as an extension function.

In *Java* the difference in the signature would be `ToolsKt.A(Any)` vs `ToolsKt.A()`.